# I am getting average_precision_score(y_test,y_predict) =1 . what is the intuition behind it?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, precision-recall

I am working on an imbalanced binary classification problem and the data is 97% in favour of a class. I am using a naive-bayes classifier and i am getting the test cv score as 1 . I have used average_precision_score() also as 1 . what is the intuition behind this result and how can i better classify this problem.

Answer (score 1):

General things you need to do:
1. CV approach that considers class imbalance (something like StratifiedKFold). This way you can be sure that you always have minor class in your test set
2. Another metric (probably even custom one that uses different weights for different error types). For example, take a look at the focal loss
3. Oversampling/downsampling techniques (imblearn in Python)

Further steps
4. Visualization (TSNE). Can give you some ideas about the general pattern
5. Feature importance and feature engineering based on important features (can make classification easier)
5. Another models (depend on (4)), boosting

Answer (score 0):

To better classify the problem you need to deal with class imbalance issue. Try reading articles on how to handle class imbalances like this one:

```
https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/03/imbalanced-classification-problem/
```